# How can I set jmockit expectations for a chain of calls using times?

Tags: jmockit, expectations

I am testing a class instance called `server` and I am using partial mocking, like this:

```
new Expectations(server) {{
    server.readPortNumber(withInstanceOf(File.class));
    result = new FileNotFoundException();
    times = 300;
}}
```

This works fine for the first 300 calls. However, the 301 call should succeed, so I was expecting something like this to work:

```
new Expectations(server) {{
    server.readPortNumber(withInstanceOf(File.class));
    result = new FileNotFoundException();
    times = 300;
    result = 100;
    times = 1;
}}
```

But it doesn't. `readPortNumber` returns `100` in it's first call, showing values were overiden.

How can I specify a chain of results using `times` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer using `Delegate`:

```
new Expectations(server) {{
    server.readPortNumber(withInstanceOf(File.class));
    result = new FileNotFoundException();
    times = 301;
    result = new Delegate() {
        int n_calls = 0;

        int delegate() throws FileNotFoundException {
            n_calls++;
            if (n_calls <= 300) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            } else {
                return 100;
            }
        }
    };
}}
```

Not sure there is a better solution, less verbose than this.

Comment: Surprisingly, this is being deprecated in current versions with the argument it's a bad design, while other frameworks support it.